# Correct way to call "realloc" in Swift with a Float array?

Tags: swift, realloc

I'm trying figure out what size to send "realloc" when I call it through Swift. **It seems that I have to add an extra byte**, but I don't understand why.

```
typealias Floats = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>

let FLOAT_SIZE = sizeof( Float )

func floats_realloc( floats:Floats, qty_of_floats:Int ) -> Floats  {

     let KLUDGE = 1 // Why?

     let qty_of_bytes = ( qty_of_floats * FLOAT_SIZE ) + KLUDGE

     let realloced_floats = Floats(

          realloc( floats, UInt( qty_of_bytes ) )

     )

     return realloced_floats

}
```

If I set KLUDGE to 0 here, this is what happens when I attempt to make room for one new member in a three member array:

In: **[0.9, 0.9, 0.9]**

Out: **[0.0, 0.0, 0.9, 0.0]**

What I would expect is:

Out: **[0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.0]**

The arrays I'm sending it are created within Swift, using

```
var foo_floats = Floats.alloc(QTY_OF_FLOATS)
```

What's wrong with my call to realloc?

Comment: if KLUDGE is 1 it works properly?

Comment: It *seems* too work with KLUDGE set to 1. But it's an intermittent thing so I'm not positive. I can't reproduce the problem in Xcode with KLUDGE at 0 or 1, for example. I see the bug only when running my app standalone, with KLUDGE set to 0.

Comment: Can you provide a full self-contained example? (What is QTY_OF_FLOATS? How is the initial array filled? How do you print the arrays? etc)

Comment: I wish I could cobble together a self-contained example, but it would be awkward. This is audio data, loaded through ExtAudioFile, copied to the clipboard as wav data, then converted back to floats... I probably should post an example, but I'm a bit of a basket case now after working all night : ( I was hoping I'd made a glaring error someone could point out

Comment: Well, it is difficult to help if you present some output, but not the code generating the output, or how the problematic realloc function is called.

Comment: @Martin Urrrgh, I can't really disagree with you, it's just that I'm nodding off ;) I'll give it a go and update my question

Comment: I tried the `realloc` without adding the 1 and did not see any issues.

Comment: @Arkku I don't see the issue when I Build+Run in Xcode. Only when I run the app without the debugger :( It probably depends on which memory is being stomped. I think it must be wrong. If I NSLog to the Console, I see the bug is in effect immediately after calling "realloc( floats, UInt( qty_of_bytes ) )" before we have even exited the function.

Comment: @Martin, Arkku: I just made a simple self-contained example in Xcode, but it's no help because I just can not get it to reproduce the issue outside of my original project. I think perhaps the code I have in this SO question *is* correct (without the +1 KLUDGE). I have no clue what is going on with my original project. Maybe the memory was freed somehow before it gets realloced. I'm stumped.

Comment: Fwiw, https://gist.github.com/charlesism/6a3c7fb0976170629249

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discussed this on Apple's Developer Forum. It turns out that using Swift's alloc allots space for a Swift array, not a C array. So if you want to use MutableUnsafePointer for a C array and "realloc" (bridged from C) you need to stick with C functions, like "malloc" (bridged from C).

By adding the following function, and using it when I initially set up my Floats array, the "realloc" bug went away:

```
func floats_alloc( qty_of_floats:Int ) -> Floats  {

      // return Floats.alloc( qty_of_floats )

      let qty_of_bytes = ( qty_of_floats * FLOAT_SIZE )

      let alloced_floats = Floats(

           malloc( UInt( qty_of_bytes ) )

      )

      return alloced_floats

 }
```

I've tested for a couple weeks now, and all is well.