# Is there something like realloc() in Swift?

Tags: swift, pointers, realloc

Now if I have allocated, and initialized a chunk of memory like this:

```
var pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Character>(5)
pointer.initializerFrom(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
```

...then how could I increase/decrease the amount of allocated memory, while keeping a reference to my data at the same time? From my understanding this is e.g. done by `realloc` in C. Is there a way to do it in Swift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct way to call "realloc" in Swift with a Float array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981124/correct-way-to-call-realloc-in-swift-with-a-float-array)

Comment: Yeah I've seen that question, but didn't really know what to make of it.

Comment: FWIW: a realloc does not make sense in most cases. Chances to get the following consecutive memory chunk are very low. Either allocate more memory from beginning on or get a new piece of memory.

Comment: Wouldn't "get[ting] a new piece of memory" be reallocation?

Comment: no it would mean getting more or less of the same memory

Comment: Wikipedia says: "realloc: increases or decreases the size of the specified block of memory. Reallocates it if needed"

Comment: Memory management is easy - in principle. But when it comes to details it's getting a nightmare. Take it for granted: there is good reason for realloc not being available. Just do alloc(new)/copy/dealloc(old) or prepare for more from beginning on.

Comment: thanks, that'a what I needed to know